# npm outdated global packages: How to actually update a package?

Tags: node.js, npm

```
❯ npm outdated -g
Package              Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
eslint                3.11.1  3.11.1  3.15.0
eslint-plugin-react    3.0.0   6.9.0   6.9.0
flow-bin              0.35.0  0.39.0  0.39.0
grunt-cli             0.1.13   1.2.0   1.2.0
gulp                   3.9.0   3.9.1   3.9.1
jshint                 2.8.0   2.9.4   2.9.4
npm                    3.8.6   4.3.0   4.2.0
uglify-js              2.7.0   2.7.5   2.7.5
```

Wondering why my eslint won't update. `npm upgrade -g -dd eslint` shows me

```
npm verb outdated not updating eslint because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
```

Which led me to try `outdated`, but either way, global `package.json` isn't a thing that exists. So why am I limited to 3.11??

According to npmjs doc,

> If there's no available semver range (i.e. you're running npm outdated
>   --global, or the package isn't included in package.json), then wanted shows the currently-installed version.

This simply doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It just got worse. `npm outdated -g` stopped working too.

Answer (score 2):

Following the de-facto workflow of `npm`, we remove and reinstall the package.

`npm remove -g eslint && npm install -g eslint`

npm, why are you so bad?

Comment: The `remove` shouldn't be needed. The `npm install -g <package>` will pick up the release tagged `latest` in the registry and install it.

Comment: For posterity's sake, @Matt's answer is the actual official answer here. If you convert that comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**To update global packages to the 'Latest' version**:

```
npx npm-check --global --update
```

That will update global packages to the 'Latest' version*. [More information is available about npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check), including the ability to update without prompting, exclude packages, etc.

---

Conversely, `npm update -g` only updates global packages to the 'Wanted' version shown by `npm outdated --global`, as globally installed packages are treated as if they are installed with a caret semver range specified.

---

Lastly, if you happen to want to update (install) a package to a version *other* than 'Latest' or 'Wanted': `npm install --global <pkg>@<version>`